# Grails 3 - conditionally ignore Spock test

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle, spock

I'd like to use Spock annotation `@IgnoreIf({condition})` to ignore test based on given environment variable when running from Intellij IDEA.

I use this in my test: `@IgnoreIf({ env.IGNORE_REDIS == 'true' })`. And set it in Gradle run configuration as following:

[image]

However, the environment property is never set. Is it an IDEA bug or am I missing something in my configuration?

Comment: You need to be sure the property passes through the gradle task. By default they do not

Comment: I pass these arguments like this `bootRun { systemProperties = System.properties }`. Is this what you meant? If I log System.properties, I see my value there. The question is how can I access it in `@IgnoreIf`closure.

Comment: `System.getProperty('IGNORE_REDIS') == 'true'`

Comment: This doesn't work either. It seems that IDEA encapsulate the run with its own system properties...

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
@IgnoreIf({ properties.IGNORE_REDIS == 'true' })
```

For me this works in Spock (not using Grails though).

Comment: Then maybe Gradle somehow does not forward the property to Grails. I am a Maven user, so I cannot help you any further here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your gradle test task to copy the system properties.

```
task integrationTest(...) {
        systemProperties System.properties // this line passes the systemproperties from gradle to your tests
}
```

And for your test in Spock:

```
@IgnoreIf({sys['IGNORE_REDIS']})
//or
@IgnoreIf({sys.IGNORE_REDIS})
//or
@IgnoreIf({sys.IGNORE_REDIS == 'true'})
```